# New tag for docx4js

Tags: support, tags

[docx4js](https://github.com/lalalic/docx4js) is a JavaScript docx parser (currently very immature), similar to docx4j.

There is a tag for "docx4j", however there is no tag for docx4js. I attempted to create a tag for it and was directed here. JavaScript is not Java, so should a tag be created for "docx4js"?